# Implementing interfaces in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, design-patterns, interface, porting

I'm learning JavaScript. My background is traditionally in Java and C#. In those environments, I could use interfaces. A lot of times, I'd have a pattern that looked like this:

```
var implementers = GetForInterface<ISomeInterface>();

foreach (var implementer in implementers)
  {
  implementer.SomeMethod();
  }
```

My question is, how do I do something similar in JavaScript? The main thing I can't seem to figure out is the `GetForInterface` part. I'm not sure what this design pattern is called.

Thank you

Comment: I think you're looking to make use of prototypal inheritance for pseudo-classes (classes and inheritance as you know it doesn't exist in JavaScript)

Comment: Well first of all there is really nothing like an "interface" in JavaScript. Don't try and make JavaScript look or act like other languages you know, *especially* Java or C#.

Comment: What language is that code snipped in? It doesn't look like valid Java, so I guess it's C#? More importantly: What is it supposed to do and when do you need that? We might be able to suggest an alternative pattern that can be used in JavaScript.

Comment: Check this : http://jscriptpatterns.blogspot.com/2013/01/javascript-interfaces.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no Interfaces in Javascript,

The design pattern you are talking about is service locator, but usually this is not the way to go on javascript .

you could use some library to do this : [service-locator](https://github.com/dimik/service-locator) or implement it your self with classes and inheritance .

a simple example to go is to hold an array of instances that inherit from the same class and you will be able to loop over them ( and activate the same method for all as desired )

Comment: Good answer except JS doesn't really have classes either...yes I know that "classes" are coming in ES6 but they're just syntactic sugar over prototypes. So it would be more accurate to say "instances that inherit from the same *prototype*".

Comment: you could use function and prototype to implement 'classes' (using the new keyword) and inheritance, you dont need to use the features of ES6 for that

Comment: My point is that they're still not really classes. The semantics are completely different from class-based languages.

Comment: i can agree with you about this . :)

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way I've seen is to use stubs and override them as needed. For example:

```js
     function getter(obj){}

     function objChecker()
       {
       try
         {
         /* Check argument length and constructor type */
         if (getter.length === 1 && getter.constructor === Function)
           {
           console.log("Correct implementation");
           return true;
           }
         else
           {
           console.log("Wrong implementation");
           return false;
           }
         }
       catch(e)
         {
         return NaN;
         }
       finally
         {
         console.log(JSON.stringify(getter))
         }
       }
 
 getter = getter;
 objChecker();
 getter = [];
 objChecker();
 getter = {};
 objChecker();
 getter = RegExp;
 objChecker();
 getter = Function;
 objChecker();
```

**References**

- [Interfaces in JavaScript](http://ajaxian.com/archives/interfaces-in-javascript)
- [How to Implement Interfaces in JavaScript](http://www.javascriptbank.com/how-implement-interfaces-in-javascript.html)
- [Public interfaces and contracts](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/actionscript/learning/oop-concepts/polymorphism-and-interfaces.html#articlecontentAdobe_numberedheader_3)
- [Annotating JavaScript for the Closure Compiler](https://github.com/google/closure-compiler/wiki/Annotating-JavaScript-for-the-Closure-Compiler)
- [comjs: A vweb take of the Component Object Model architecture](https://github.com/sanagnos/comjs)
- [try...catch...finally Statement (JavaScript) | Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/scripting/javascript/reference/try-dot-dot-dot-catch-dot-dot-dot-finally-statement-javascript)